# Sending data form registration forms

Tags: encryption, php, databases

I understand that sending data from the user to the server, unencrypted, is a bad practice.  That is logical.

So how do I encrypt 'userside' and send the data to the server in encrypted form?

Can anyone suggest a good practice example?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of encrypting in Javascript?  (What if the user has disabled Javascript?)

Comment: If you are encrypting using Javascript a user could easily reverse engineer your application and discover the key. The best solution is to just use HTTPS

Comment: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/ discusses in detail why using JavaScript for cryptography is a bad idea. And kudos for recognizing that JS should be a choice that is not forced on the user of the app.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, u confirmed why not to use JavaScript. So besides using https is there any other option for doing this?

Comment: Btw, tnx for the matasano article, very good reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard solution is to use SSL (HTTPS).

Please spend some time with the search tool on this site.  You will find these questions have all been answered on other questions, so you can find lots of good information.  For instance, a search on "Javascript encryption" will find a lot of information about the pitfalls of encrypting on the client-side in Javascript.

Make sure to learn about how to enable SSL sitewide; about HSTS; and about the secure flag on cookies.

In general, I recommend OWASP as an excellent resource with a lot of information about good practices for securing web services.

Comment: Tnx. I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

other than confidentiality, https solves a lot of other problems. There is no safe way to send passwords in the clear or encoded or obfuscated somehow. Https really is the best solution.

Comment: Ok, yeah i was just asking for other posibilities, because ssl is an expensive venture. Luckily for me im not building and application which has any really harmful options for users (what i mean its not a banking or buying or anything uf that sorts) I still want to make it as secure as possible given the financial restrictions. So thank your for the answer :D

Comment: You don't have to *purchase* a SSL cert - try someone like cacert.org or search 'free ssl certificates" or just generate a self-signed cert if you are just in the testing phase.